# what to choose between IMU and GYRO

Tags: navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,

i have some troubles with the navigation stack ,i'm working with the wheel encoder and  it seems that the odometry is drifting ( when rotating )  so i'm looking to add another sensor like an IMU or GYRO  compatible with ros  but i'm new in ros and i don't know what to choose  so i'm wondering if  you have any advices ?

thanks ,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294371/what-to-choose-between-imu-and-gyro/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-06-18**:
Gyro is part of IMU that read robot angle velocity. So choosing IMU or gyro is even not right question.

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-06-18**:
thanks for answering  i saw somewhere gyro sensor that's why i'm confused  , so which IMU sensor is working fine with ros ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're working in a solely planar environment and only looking for yaw, a gyro would be nice, that is all the turtlebot has.

This listing gives you a non-exhaustive list of drivers available as a jump off point. http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors

If you find a hobby IMU from adafruit / similar vendors, chances are there's a simple minimum example for reading values somewhere you can wrap in ROS in 30 minutes, many themselves will have unsupported ROS drivers from other users.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-06-20**:
thanks for answering

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-06-20**:
If you think this is the right answer, please click the check so that the topic can be closed